# JQuery - change dynamic link to plain text inside $.each

Tags: jquery

I inherited this jquery code in a webapp:

```
$.each(data, function (i, v) {
  d.find('table.datatable').dataTable().fnAddData([
      $('<div />').append($('<a />', {
          text: v.MemberName,
          title: v.MemberName,
          href: 'javascript:void(0);',
          onclick: 'selectMember(' + JSON.stringify(v) + ')'
      })).html(),
      $('<div />').append($('<a />', {
          text: v.AccountID,
          title: v.AccountID,
          href: 'MemberAccount.aspx?accountid=' + v.AccountID,
          target: '_blank'
      })).html(),
      v.MailingAddress,
      v.ScanCode,
      v.IsActive ? 'Yes' : 'No',
  ]);
});
```

I'm not great with jquery. Notice the 2nd structure that relates to AccountID, in which it's building a link with text, title, href, target. I need the AccountID data to remain, but the link to go away. No link, no href, just leave AccountID data. I have poked and tweaked at this for a half hour, and each time I try to strip away link-related stuff, the whole thing breaks and I don't know why.

Help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So just change

```
$('<div />').append($('<a />', {
     text: v.AccountID,
     title: v.AccountID,
     href: 'MemberAccount.aspx?accountid=' + v.AccountID,
     target: '_blank'
})).html(),
```

to

```
v.AccountID,
```

What you're originally doing is passing in this as the HTML into that cell

```
<a title="accountID" href="MemberAccount.aspx?accountid=AccountID" target="_blank">AccountID</a>
```

if you just pass in `v.AccountID` - you will only get the AccountID as the HTML in that cell